# Filter a file with output of another command

Tags: bash, zsh

I have an external command, say `check_this`, which would spit out YES or NO for a file piped to it

```
cat myfile | check_this

YES
NO
YES
YES
...
```

Now I want to get all the lines in myfile with YES results. Is there a way to do this? Currently I use a tempfile, save it to another file, then use paste + grep, which is cumbersome and not robust.

Comment: it outputs yes or no for every line?  So in your output we can assume line 1 is yes, line 2 is no, line 3 is yes, and line 4 is no?

Comment: yes, each line will produce either YES or NO.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `awk`:

```
<myfile check_this | awk '
  !check_processed {if ($1 == "YES") yes[FNR]; next}
  FNR in yes' - check_processed=1 myfile
```

`awk` records which line numbers of `check_this`'s output start with a `YES` word in the `yes` hash table, and then prints the lines of `myfile` whose number are in that `yes` hash table.

Answer (score 0):

A variant of @StéphaneChazelas' perfectly good `awk`-based solution, that is less compact but perhaps easier to read because it does not resort to an external variable (`check_processed` in his notation), would be:

```
$ awk 'FNR == NR {if ($1 == "YES") yes[FNR];next} 
       FNR != NR && FNR in yes'   <(check_this <myfile) myfile
```

*Note*: @RakeshSharma remarks that the simultaneous use of `next` (1st line) and of the test `FNR != NR` (2nd line) is a redundancy. Users of that pattern can remove one or the other with no change in output, as in:

```
$ awk 'FNR == NR {if ($1 == "YES") yes[FNR];next} 
       FNR in yes'   <(check_this <myfile) myfile
```

Comment: The `FNR != NR` is redundant and can be removed. Or, remove the `next` from the previous line.

Comment: @RakeshSharma: You are 100% right.  You could even see the simultaneous use of `next` and the test `FNR != NR` as an anti-pattern here.  It was just meant as a quick illustration of `awk`'s versatility, geared toward people not fully conversant with the idiom, or not comfortable with using external variables declared for the subshell on same cmd line (see StéphaneChazelas' answer)... I will nevertheless edit the answer with a small comment mentioning you for good measure. Good catch.

Comment: Note that the `FNR == NR` approaches in general don't work properly when the first file is empty which is why I prefer the `!flag`/`flag=1` approach. In this case though, it wouldn't be a problem as if `myfile` is empty, the output of `check_this` would also be empty. See [Bypass a nawk snippet if the input file is empty](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/237105)

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of the `GNU` version of the **dc** utility to basically implement a `grep -f` functionality.

```
dc -e "
$(< myfile check_this | sed -e 's/NO/0/;s/YES/1/' | tac)
[q]sq [p]sp [?z0=qr1=psxz0<?]s?
l?x
" < <(< myfile sed -e 's/.*/[&]/')
```

- As a first step we load the `check_this` utility's output, booleanized appropriately (YES=>1, NO=>0), and pushed onto the stack. The next line from the input file is read and pushed on the stack. print it if the 2nd stack element is a 1.
- Then we clear out the top 2 stack elements. Repeat until eof.

Answer (score 0):

**GNU awk aka gawk+paste**:

```
$ < myfile check_this \
   | paste myfile -      \
   | gawk '/YES$/ && NF--';
```

```
$ < myfile check_this \
    |  perl -lpe '
      @ARGV && do{
        /YES/ && $h{$.}++;
        eof && close(ARGV);
        next;
       };
        print if $h{$.};
  ' - myfile
```

**GNU sed** with `extended regex` mode ON:

```
$ < myfile check_this |
    sed -nE '
        1{:a;H;n;/^(YES|NO)$/ba;}
        G;/\n\nYES/P
        s/.*\n\n(YES|NO)/\n/;h
    ' - myfile
```

store the check_this output in hold and fir every line of myfile determine the leading value for hold is a yes. Then print the myfile line. Clip leading two elements from pattern space and re-store (NOT "restore" mind you) the pattern into hold space.